# How can I redirect with submit button in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have  this HTML:

```
<% provide(:contact, "active") %>
<% provide(:title, "Contacto | Recotiendame") %>
<div align="center">
  <h1 id_"page_title">Contactanos!</h1>
  <div class="skinny_wrapper wrapper_padding"
      <%= form_for contact_path, url: @done do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :Nombre %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :Nombre, required: true %>

        <br>

        <%= f.label :Email %><br>
        <%= f.email_field :Email, required: true %>

        <br>

        <%= f.label :Mensaje %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :Mensaje, as: :text %>

        <div class= "hidden">
            <%= f.label :nickname %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :nickname, hint: 'dejalo en blanco' %>
        </div>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit 'Enviar Mensaje', class: "button" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

with this controller:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Gracias por su mensaje. Lo contactaremos luego!'
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'No se pudo enviar el mensaje.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the submit button does nothing. How can I make it work to redirect me to create? I have seen lots of answers to this question but none works for me.

**EDIT 1**

When I did `@done`, it was only to try things.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not entirely sure what you mean. When do you want to be redirected to create? If you click the submit button it should take you to create, but this is not the same thing as html-redicretion - so I'm just trying t be clear on what you want to happen. If I had to guess, I think you've got your `form_for` fields wrong. Normally you'd have something like: `form_for @contact` and it'd Just Work, but if you wanted to override the default url, you'd pass a different url eg `form_for @contact, url: contacts_path` (note the plural is important).

Comment: I don't know what `@done` is meant to be... but it probably shouldn't be there... and putting the `contact_path` has two incorrect things about it: 1) you shouldn't have a url at that point, but an object (in this case the object is the contact), and secondly `contact_path` is for showing a single contact that has already been saved, for creating a new contact, you need `contacts_path` (the idea is that you're posting a new contact to the set of contacts).

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I think you've got your form_for fields wrong. Normally you'd have something like: `form_for @contact` and it'd Just Work, but if you wanted to override the default url, you'd pass a different url eg

```
form_for @contact, url: contacts_path`
```

(note the plural is important).

I don't know what `@done` is meant to be... but it probably shouldn't be there... and putting the contact_path has two incorrect things about it:

1) you shouldn't have a url at that point, but an object (in this case the object is the contact)

2) `contact_path` is for showing a single contact that has already been saved, for creating a new contact, you need `contacts_path` (the idea is that you're posting a new contact to the set of contacts).

Comment: Hi!, thanks what should i put instead of @done?, i'm pretty new in rails to so i'm pretty much lost here, what i am trying to do is that when i click the button it redirect me to the create.html.erb
  `<h1 id_"page_title">Contactanos!</h1>

  <div class="skinny_wrapper wrapper_padding">
   <h1> Gracias por su mensaje! </h1>
   <p>Le responderemos pronto.</p>
  </div>`

Comment: you shouldn't need `@done` at all... in fact you shouldn't need the `url:` component at all, if you use `form_for @contact`. Also - it's not the submit button that redirects you anywhere. The submit button takes you to the `create` action in the controller... the controller will process the values you sent it and then it will render the `create.html.erb` template -> that's where you put the `Contactanos!` content.

Comment: BTW, as a newbie Rails developer, I strongly recommend you read your way through the Rails Guides here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ (if you haven't already). They are a great way to level up in your Rails knowledge :)

Comment: But when i do @contact it sends me this message error 
`undefined method contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x0055e2a0849e68>:0x007f3108db1d30>
Did you mean?  contact_path`

Comment: i have read parts of the guide (its pretty long and i have like 3 days using rails) But i have much questions because of a tutorial i have seen and he does things like that D:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIoORYeBdhs